# Angular stop timer

Tags: angularjs, timer

I am dealing with a angular timer problem.

what i need is , when a button is clicked the timer should stop and when another button clicked it should resume.But in my case the timer stops but it doesn't resume correctly.

Here is my code....

Controller

```
$scope.startTime = new Date().getTime();
                        $scope.delTime = new Date();
                        $scope.delTime.setMinutes($scope.delTime.getMinutes() + 20);
                        $scope.endTime = parseInt(data.lock_timestamp);
```

View

```
<timer end-time="endTime">{{hhours}} : {{mminutes}} : {{sseconds}}</timer>
```

Here is my button

```
<button class="btns red-skin sml-btn lrg-radius" ng-click="timerToggle()" type="button">{{timerStatus}}</button>
```

here is the code where i used to toggle the timer

```
$scope.$on('timer-started', function() {
  $scope.timerStatus = "started";
});
$scope.$on('timer-stopped', function() {
  $scope.timerStatus = "stopped";
});
$scope.$on('timer-reset', function() {
  $scope.timerStatus = "reset";
});
$scope.timerStart = function() {
  $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
};
$scope.timerStop = function() {
//alert($scope.endTime);
  $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
};
$scope.timerResume = function() {
  $scope.$broadcast('timer-resume');
};
$scope.timerToggle = function() {
  switch ($scope.timerStatus) {
    case "started":
      $scope.timerStop();
      break;
    case "stopped":
      $scope.timerResume();
      break;
    case "reset":
      $scope.timerStart();
      break;
  }  
};
```

but when this function works it stops the timer but actually it works in back ground.

i.e.
if i stop the timer in " 00:00:10 " it displays " 00:00:10 " but when resumed after 5 seconds the timer  shows " 00:00:05 " and starts, but what i want is stopped in " 00:00:10 " it displays " 00:00:10 " and  when resumed after 5 seconds the timer  should start from " 00:00:10 ".

Please find me a solution ,,Waiting for a response..

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: need more code..

Comment: I 've posted more code,please check .